# What does 'とした’ mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles

I'm looking for a bit of help understanding what とした means in this sentence describing the UN flag:

> この旗は、真ん中に北極を中心**とした**世界地図が[描]{か}いてあります。

While I can get the gist of the meaning, can someone help explain exactly what とした means here? I googled around a bit, but wasn't really able to figure it out. Especially, it would be great to get an understanding of this grammatical construction so I can use it / recognize it again.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「A を B **と**する」

is a common set phrase meaning:

> "to regard A as B", "to assume A to be B", etc.

There is no "real and logical" center of the world possible on a two-dimentional world map, agreed?  Each world map, according to its purpose, simply must regard someplace as the center.

(As a kid growing up in Japan, I never knew why our part of the world was called the "Far East" because on the world maps used in Japan, Japan was always located right in the middle.  I was naturally shocked when I saw the Western version of the world map for the first time.)

> 「この旗{はた}は、真{ま}ん中{なか}に北極{ほっきょく}を中心{ちゅうしん}**とした**世界地図{せかいちず}が​描{か}​いてあります。」

On this particular map, the North Pole is in the center because that is what they "decided" to place in the middle.  It served its own purpose that way.

> "Right in the middle of this banner, a world map is drawn with the North Pole as its center."

Comment: 「真ん中に」は何を修飾しているんでしょうか。。北極を中心とした世界地図が、 旗の真ん中に描いてあります、って意味ですかね？

Comment: 「旗の真ん中」という意味でしょうね。恐らく国連旗についての文章かと思います。あかん、標準語になってもうてる。

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense! (And as for the map anecdote, when I was teaching English there, a few of my students said the same thing about why Japan was called the "far east"! Super interesting for me too, as I had never stopped to think that other parts of the world might draw a map differently).